# print dict keys and values using another variable

Tags: python-2.7

I have dict 'SR' as given below.

```
    >>> SR =  {'threshold':'95', 'math':'mean', 'dir':'down'}
    >>> SR
    {'threshold': '95', 'dir': 'down', 'math': 'mean'}
    >>> var='SR'
```

How can i print all key & value of 'SR' using variable var . My script dynamically select dict name  based on some logic , store it in some variable . So I have to print dict values and keys using an another variable. Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the various `dict`s into another `dict` and look it up that way.

```
d = {
    'SR': {'threshold': '95', 'math': 'mean', 'dir': 'down'},
    'AB': {'foo': 'bar'},
    'XY': {'blah': 'baz'},
}

which_to_print = 'SR'

for key, value in d[which_to_print].items():
    print key, value
```